# What's the proper SE site to ask about Joomla?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I don't know if this question goes here. I searched [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and found nothing, and I don't think [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) is the proper place either.

I searched the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposals and found [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9494/joomla-answers), but it looks it's not going anywhere... is there another site I am missing, or is there nothing on [SE](https://stackexchange.com/) (yet)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's about

- installation of Joomla

  - Server Fault
- how to do x in Joomla

  - Web Apps SE
  - *maybe* Super User

    - yeah, it's kinda software-y, but ultimately it's not something you install on your machine; it's on the Internet or an intranet
- writing a patch for Joomla

  - Stack Overflow
- why a specific part of Joomla works, with source code reference

  - also Stack Overflow
- whether Joomla is the right choice for you

  - Programmers SE
- your website that's backed by Joomla

  - Pro Webmasters SE

Answer (score 7):

Update a couple of years later. The new Stack Exchange site for Joomla is in public beta so you can ask all you questions there:

http://joomla.stackexchange.com