# Is there a Stack Exchange for Joomla?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Stack Overflow is really great, but is there a place where I can find all Joomla-related questions like [Drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) or [WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) have?

Comment: We should have a let-me-search-that-on-area51-for-you tool.

Comment: @CamilStaps - Fair play to the guy. He is new to Stackexchange so is not expected to know everything about it.

Comment: @Lodder okay, I see - didn't check that. My apologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the proper SE site to ask about Joomla?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66915/whats-the-proper-se-site-to-ask-about-joomla)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it should have been done ages ago. Please help the process by committing to it. Lots of us have been waiting for a long time for this as people are starting to use Stack Overflow more and more for Joomla support rather than using the Joomla forums.

<strike>We need **13** more committers with a rep of over 200 on any other site</strike>

**UPDATE:**

The [Joomla Stackexchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) site is now in public beta!

Comment: Thanks ;) Hopefully other people will ask the same question or see the proposal

Comment: There is nothing to do with required committers in this answer. It won't help anyone in future. So editing just such a number is not a good edit.

Comment: @hims056  -Not really what the OP asked. I only update the number for the benefit of those who **might** be interested.

Answer (score 8):

<del>There is a proposal on Area 51: [Joomla Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla).</del>

Now it's open: [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6):

Now there is at http://joomla.stackexchange.com